# Cannot search by Division attribute

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to create security group for filtering purposes, they do not exist yet and I am wanting to create them.

I would like to get all my AD user and select the value of the `Division` field.

With that field I'd like to add them to a group in an OU called "SafetyNet"

If the group that matches the name of their division exist - they would be added to that group. If not, the group would be created and then they would be added.

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
$users = get-aduser -filter "enabled -eq '$true' -and division -like '*'" -properties division

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $group = get-adgroup $user.division

    if ($group) {
        $groupname = get-adgroup -Filter "name -like '$($user.division)'"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -members $user
    }
    else {
        new-adgroup -name $user.division -SamAccountName $user.division -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope global -path "OU=TinyPulse, DC=smh, DC=org"
        start-sleep -Seconds 5 
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.division -Members $user
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem like division is a searchable attribute which make this difficult.

Comment: First, we'd recommend not using `-Properties *` as that will be slow. Find enabled users with `division` attribute set: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(divsion=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -Properties division`

Comment: It seems you can search by division.